# Jackson - how to parse string array to collection of objects

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to post some data to my REST controller. The trouble part of my JSON look's like:

```
{
    "externalLinks": ["link1", "link2"],
    "lectureRequirements": ["requirement1", "requirement2"]
}
```

I need to parse it to two collections of models:

```
public class Lecture {

    // other fields...

    private List<LectureExternalLink> lectureExternalLinks;

    private List<LectureRequirement> lectureRequirements;
}
```

Both classes - LectureExternalLink and LectureRequirement has only two fields- id and string parameter. I want to parse incoming string array to model collection where string goes to corresponding field in model class. Is there any way to do that using jackson annotations?

Comment: What do you want the ID to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a magic annotation to do this. `LectureExternalLink` and `LectureRequirement` can deserialize to string if you add single-String constructor/factory method to you POJOs

```
// OPTION 1 with constructor
private static class POJO{
    private String name;

    public POJO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

// OPTION 2 with factory method
private static class POJO{
    private String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public static POJO POJO(String name) {
        POJOlink = new POJO();
        link.name = name;
        return link;
    }
}
```

You could also use `@JsonValue` above `getName()` to serialize it back to `{"externalLinks":["link1","link2"],"lectureRequirements":["requirement1","requirement2"]}`

If you can't change your POJO for some reason, i think the only way for you to go is to create custom deserializer like this one:

```
private static class MyJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LectureExternalLink> {
    @Override
    public LectureExternalLink deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
                                                           throws IOException {
        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        LectureExternalLink val= new LectureExternalLink();
        val.setName(value);
        return val;
    }
}
```

---

**Full Demo:**

```
private static final String json ="{\n" +
        "    \"externalLinks\": [\"link1\", \"link2\"],\n" +
        "    \"lectureRequirements\": [\"requirement1\", \"requirement2\"]\n" +
        "}";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Lecture l = mapper.readValue(json,Lecture.class);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(l));

}

public static class Lecture {
    @JsonProperty("externalLinks")
    private List<LectureExternalLink> lectureExternalLinks;

    @JsonProperty("lectureRequirements")
    private List<LectureRequirement> lectureRequirements;

    public List<LectureExternalLink> getLectureExternalLinks() {
        return lectureExternalLinks;
    }

    public void setLectureExternalLinks(List<LectureExternalLink> lectureExternalLinks) {
        this.lectureExternalLinks = lectureExternalLinks;
    }

    public List<LectureRequirement> getLectureRequirements() {
        return lectureRequirements;
    }

    public void setLectureRequirements(List<LectureRequirement> lectureRequirements) {
        this.lectureRequirements = lectureRequirements;
    }
}

@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
private static class LectureRequirement {
    private String name;

    private Integer id;

    public LectureRequirement(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @JsonValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}


@JsonDeserialize(using = MyJsonDeserializer.class)
public static class LectureExternalLink {
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @JsonValue
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

private static class MyJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LectureExternalLink> {

    @Override
    public LectureExternalLink deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        LectureExternalLink val= new LectureExternalLink();
        val.setName(value);
        return val;
    }
}
```